# Terraform aws provider - how to use default region from ~/.aws/config

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-regions

In my `main.tf` I have an empty aws provider defined

```
provider aws {}
```

In the absence of environment variables the aws provider picks the `[default]` credentials from `~/.aws/credentials`. However I still get prompted to enter the region:

```
>terraform plan
provider.aws.region
  The region where AWS operations will take place. Examples
  are us-east-1, us-west-2, etc.

  Enter a value:
```

How can I get the aws provider to automatically pick up the corresponding region to the `[default]` credentials as defined in `~/.aws/config`?

Comment: you can assign as a variable as well.

Answer (score 8):

AWS provider has **profile** attribute but it does not pick up the region from .aws/config.

```
$ cat main.tf
provider aws {
     profile="default"
}

$ terraform plan
provider.aws.region
  The region where AWS operations will take place. Examples
  are us-east-1, us-west-2, etc.
...
```

The way I can think of now is using the environment variable (I use this way).

```
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(aws configure get region --profile default)
$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.
```

Comment: Sad though, one would think terraform would pick up the region the same way the aws cli uses it. Anyway, thanks for the great lead.

Answer (score 2):

If the only reason that you have the `provider` block is to reference the region in your code then you can simply use the [aws_region data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/region) which allows you to reference the current region instead of having the `provider` block (the region should be picked up from the default profile in this case I believe)

```
data "aws_region" "current-region" {}

// Then get the region using
data.aws_region.current-region.name
```